# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/IfNull while executing SQL on Ignite DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

I have a spark dataframe which I have written to Ignite format

```
`spark_df.write.format("ignite")\
        .mode("overwrite")\
        .option("table", "processed_logs")\
        .option("primaryKeyFields","player_id")\
        .option("config",config_file).save()`
```

Next, I read the same into a dataframe

```
`ignite_df = spark.read.format("ignite")\
    .option("table", "processed_logs")\
    .option("config", config_file)\
    .load()`
```

I created a table view on top of it

```
`ignite_df.createOrReplaceTempView("ignite_table")`
```

When I run SQL queries against ignite_table, I get this error

Query ->     `spark.sql("Select * from ignite_table where logins > 2").show()`

Error ->
`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o197.showString. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/IfNull at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.optimization.SystemExpressions$.apply(SystemExpressions.scala:35) at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.optimization.package$.$anonfun$exprsAllowed$2(package.scala:100)`

Full error -> https://pastebin.pl/view/f33b2e80

The query works if I use python thin client but I require this implementation only.
Please help me resolve this.

PS : Spark Version -> 3.3.2
Ignite version -> 2.15.0

Answer (score 0):

From Apache Ignite [documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.15.0/extensions-and-integrations/ignite-for-spark/overview#supported-spark-version),

> Apache Ignite comes with two modules that support different versions
> of Apache Spark:
>
> ```
> ignite-spark-ext 1.0.0 — integration with Spark 2.3
>
> ignite-spark-ext 2.0.0 — integration with Spark 2.4
> ```

Looks like spark 3.x is not compatible even with latest ignite version.

Comment: But then both Spark 2.3 and 2.4 are giving this weird error
`ImportError: cannot import name 'print_exec' from 'pyspark.cloudpickle'`

Answer (score 0):

Spark 3.0 is supported  but it's not documented:

https://downloads.apache.org/ignite/ignite-extensions/ignite-spark-ext/3.0.0/

Try this version for your version of Spark.